# React Native- Switch navigator not working properly

Tags: javascript, react-native, axios, react-navigation

I'm using switch navigator, bottom tab navigator, and stack navigator as follows. 
**App.js**

```
const SignoutScreen =()=>{}
const bottomTabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator({
  Profile:{
    screen:Profile,
    navigationOptions:{headerShown:false}
  },
  Signout: {
    screen: SignoutScreen, 
    navigationOptions: {
        tabBarLabel: 'Signout', 
        tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => (
            <SimpleLineIcons name="logout" color={tintColor} size={20} />
        ), 
        tabBarOnPress: async ({navigation}) => {
            console.log("Pressed")
            await AsyncStorage.clear();
            navigation.navigate('Login');
        }
    }
},
  Other:{screen:Other,navigationOptions:{tabBarLabel:'Screen C',headerShown:false}}},
  {
    
    defaultNavigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
      
      tabBarIcon: ({ focused, horizontal, tintColor }) => {
        const { routeName } = navigation.state;
        //let IconComponent = Ionicons;
        let iconName;
        if (routeName === 'Profile') {
          
          iconName = focused
            ? 'users'
            : 'users';
          // Sometimes we want to add badges to some icons.
          // You can check the implementation below.
          //IconComponent = HomeIconWithBadge;
        } else if (routeName === 'Other') {
          iconName = focused ? 'comments' : 'comments';
        }

        // You can return any component that you like here!
        return <FontAwesome name={iconName} size={25} color={tintColor} />;
      },
    }),
    tabBarOptions: {
      activeTintColor: 'tomato',
      inactiveTintColor: 'gray',
    },
  })

const switchNavigation = createSwitchNavigator({
  Login:{
    screen:Login,
    navigationOptions:{
      headerShown:false,
    },
  },
  Other:{
    screen:bottomTabNavigator,
    navigationOptions:{
      headerShown:false,
    }
    },
})

const AppStack = createStackNavigator({
  Login:{
    screen:switchNavigation,
    navigationOptions:{
      headerShown:false
    }
  },
  
  
    SignUp:{
      screen:SignUp,
      navigationOptions:{
        headerShown:false
      }
    }
  
},{
  initialRouteName:'Login'
}
)

const container = createAppContainer(AppStack)

export default container
```

When a user logs in, he's navigated to the **Profile** screen and login credentials are stored using **AsyncStorage** .
The Profile screen hosts a bottom tab navigator, to the 'Other' screen, and a logout button. There's also a network call made on the Profile screen using Axios. When I click on **logout** button it's executing the catch block of the network call instead of navigating to the desired screen(Login). I tried completely removing the network call block and then tried logging out, in that case, there was no response or any error messages. 
**Profile.js**

```
.
.
.

async componentDidMount() {
        this._isMounted = true
        //this.getToken()
        await AsyncStorage.getItem("token").then((token) => {
            var tkn = JSON.parse(token)
            this.setState({
                token: tkn
            });
        }).catch(err => {
            console.log(err)
            
        })

        await AsyncStorage.getItem("username").then((usr) => {
            var usrnm = JSON.parse(usr)
            this.setState({
                username:usrnm
            });
        }).catch(err => {
            console.log(err)
        })


        axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/endpoint/', { headers: { 'Authorization': " Token " + this.state.token } })    
            .then(response => { 
               
              console.log(response)
            })  
            .catch(error => {   
                console.log("Error is:" + error)    //This line is executed whenever I press logout.
                //this.props.navigation.navigate('Login')
            })

    }

    


    async getToken() {
        this._isMounted = true
        try {
            var string = await AsyncStorage.getItem("token")
            var tkn = JSON.parse(string)
            //alert(tkn)
            this.setState({ token: tkn }, () => console.log("Token value set"))
        }
        catch (error) {
            console.log("Something went wrong")

        }
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        this._isMounted = false
    }
.
.
.
```

**Login.js**

```
.
.
.
componentDidMount(){
        this._isMounted = true
        if(this.getToken()!==null){ //checking if token exists or not.
            this.props.navigation.navigate('App')
        }
    }

async getToken(){
        try{
            var string = await AsyncStorage.getItem("token")
            var tkn = JSON.parse(string)
            //console.log(tkn)
            this.setState({token:tkn})
        }
        catch(error){
            console.log("Something went wrong")
        }
    }
.
.
.
```

This problem occurs only when I try to use **Switch Navigator**. Without switch navigator, i.e, only using a stack navigator it works just fine. The main purpose of using a switch navigator is to maintain control flow(exit to the system's home screen when the back button or equivalent is pressed by a logged-in user, instead of navigating to the login screen). 
Please shed some light to fix this bug/error. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a thorough inspection, I came to a realization that the issue was not directly connected to switch navigator, but a combined result of switch navigator and a coding bug.
If you closely look at the above snippets, you can observe that in **Login.js**'s **componentDidMount** I'm checking, if a user is already authenticated or not by checking if any token is stored or not. i.e `if(this.getToken()!==null)` .
After hours of debugging, I found out that `this.getToken()` returned nothing, means calling the function would return `undefined`, and in the *if* block I was checking if the value was `null` or not. So, basically, When the user was logged in and tried logging out, the **AsyncStorage** values would be cleared and navigated to the **Login** screen. When the **Login** screen would show up, the componentDidMount would fire up, calling the **this.getToken()** would return `undefined` which is not equal to `null` implying the execution of the **if** block which would again navigate to the **Profile** screen, completing a cirlce.
A simple fix is to change the condition to **if(this.getToken()!==undefined&&this.getToken()!==null) , or if(this.getToken()) . 

TIP:**A good rule of thumb while making sanity check is to cover all the possible cases (NaN, undefined, null)(only when the function could return the said values), it's best to use `if(function()){...}` .